# How can this nullpointer possibly happen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a tabbed application, with fragments as tabs. The app is about 5 years old.

This is the same code I have had for a long time, but in the last weeks, I have suddenly a couple of **nullpointers** in the **Google console** crash logs!

I cannot see how it is possible that this code could cause a **nullpointer**, so I am hoping that someone can see something that i can't.

```
    private TextView switchSpace;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedState);
    initGUIComponents();        
    checkSpace();
}

private void initGUIComponents() {
    switchSpace = getView().findViewById(R.id.rightText);        
}

private void checkSpace() {
    if (shouldShowComponent) {
        switchSpace.setText(textToShow);
        switchSpace.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        switchSpace.setVisibility(View.GONE);//NULLPOINTER IN CONSOLE!!
    }
}
```

The stack trace shows that it's the call to checkSpace in `onActivityCreated` that causes the **nullpointer**. Again, it has always worked, I only have like 3 crashes in total, but still. How can this happen?

Pointers much appreciated.

EDIT, stacktrace:

> at x.y.z.tabs.MainFragment.checkSpace (MainFragment.java:268)
>     at x.y.z.tabs.MainFragment.onActivityCreated (MainFragment.java:81)
>     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated (Fragment.java:2363)
>     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1442)
>     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1740)
>     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1809)
>     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps (BackStackRecord.java:799)
>     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps (FragmentManagerImpl.java:2580)
>     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether (FragmentManagerImpl.java:2367)
>     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute (FragmentManagerImpl.java:2

Comment: is this `Fragment` the first fragment in your Tab / `ViewPager`? (also, are you using a `ViewPager`?) Can you post the stack-trace? Is this `Fragment` loaded directly when the `Activity` is created? Or the `Activity` is created, then you create the `Fragment`/s e.g after some user input? How many `Fragment`'s do you have?

Comment: do view.findViewById in onViewCreated using View parameter of it instead of getView()

Comment: Nepster, why would that matter? (honest question!) I do have my doubts, it has always looked like this, right or not, and i have never had any issues before.

Comment: Payloc, it is indeed the first tab, out of five.I am not using viewpager, but a tabhost with fragments that i show and hide. Added stacktrace above

Answer (score 0):

- Is `shouldShowComponent` initialized?
- Are you missing a cast to `TextView` when calling `setText(textToShow)`?
- Are you sure `getView().findViewById(R.id.rightText);` returns the right view (if any at all?)

Comment: In the latest SDK, if I'm not wrong, `findViewById` returns `<? extends View>` instead of `View`; which does no require a cast. Still, that would not trigger a `NullPointerException`...

Comment: Not sure about this (and probably not applicable in your case), but not all classes that extend `View` have a `setText()` method, right? If so, wouldn't that potentially lead to a NPE?

Comment: @lewinder96 No, the compiler would complain and would not even let you build. `NullPointerException` is a type of `RuntimeException`, which as the name says happens on runtime

Comment: @payloc Sounds reasonable. Rewrote answer to remove redundancies :)

Comment: shouldShowComponent is a boolean, so always initialized, yeah. Yes, just refactored the code and removed the casts

Answer (score 0):

make a view object like that:

```
 private TextView switchSpace;
 private View view;
```

in Oncreateview of your fragment initialize your text view like that

```
       //in on create view


        // initialize view
       view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourfragment, container, false);

        //find text view  
       switchSpace = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.rightText); 

       return view;
```

then in On activity created do what ever

```
          @Override
          public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedState) {
          super.onActivityCreated(savedState);

          checkSpace();
          }
```

Comment: setContentView is done in `onCreate()'-method of the activity, no?

Comment: he didn't set the content view in on create, according to his code.

Comment: I am of course inflating the view in onCreateView. Otherwise it would never work. This nullpointer i am talking about only happens very very rarely. But it should never happen :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `getView()` to connect the view with its id. According to documentation of lifecycle of `Fragment` a `getView()` can be called before `View` is inflated and when that happens your `getView()` is actually `null` and because of that `getView()` can not connect your `TextView` with id and `TextView` is `null`. Then `exception` is throwing when app tries to preform an action on view which is `null`. So just connect your `TextView` with its id inside `OnCreatView` using inflated `View`. This is my opinion I might be wrong but this would explain why `exception` was not thrown always instead sometimes (when `getView()` is called before view is actually inflated)

Comment: Also thought of that, but `getView()` returning `null` would trigger a `NullPointerException` in `initGUIComponents()`, but OP says the stack-trace shows the Exception in `checkSpace()`.

Comment: Not necessarily. Speaking about this case a `TextView` can have `null` value. Just preforming some action (in this case trying to change `Visibility`) on `TextView` which has `null` value will throw exception.

Comment: Alright I thought you meant the value returned by `getView()` would be `null`. In such case, calling a method from a `null` reference would indeed trigger a `NPE`.

Comment: Good theory, but i agree with payloc. If getView returned null, i would already have gotten a nullpointer earlier, in initGuiComponents(): changeButton = getView().findViewById(R.id.changeButton); FindViewById on a null getView().